# Problemas para fechar outra planilha por VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Estou rodando o código abaixo para comparação de dados de planilhas diferentes. Esta rodando corretamente, mas não estou conseguindo fechar as planilhas de origem dos dados. Já tentei com '.Close', '.Quit' e '= Nothing', de todas as formas a aparece o erro 'subscrito fora de intervalo".

```
Sub teste()

extrato = Range("B1").Value
comparativa = Range("B2").Value

Dim ws As Workbook
Set ws = Application.Workbooks.Add

    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Contraparte"
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Faturamento"


Data = Replace(Replace(Now(), ":", "."), "/", "_")
ws.SaveAs ("C:\Users\leandro.lazari\Desktop\Financeiro\" & Data & ".xlsx")

'Abre Planilha extrato e copia lançamentos e valores
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\leandro.lazari\Desktop\Financeiro\" & extrato & ".xls")
    Range("E12:F12").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

'Cola dados de extrato
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\leandro.lazari\Desktop\Financeiro\" & Data & ".xlsx")
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

'Abre Planilha extrato e copia lançamentos e valores
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\leandro.lazari\Desktop\Financeiro\" & comparativa & ".xlsx")

    Range("A2:B2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    With Selection
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlLTR
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Copy

'Cola dados de extrato
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\leandro.lazari\Desktop\Financeiro\" & Data & ".xlsx")
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


'Checa os valores que convergem e retorna as convergências
i = 2
j = 3
    Do Until Range("I" & i) = ""

        Range("K" & i).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(R[0]C[-2],C[-5],1,FALSE), ""ENCONTRADO""), ""NÃO ENCONTRADO"")"

            If Cells(i, 11).Value = "ENCONTRADO" Then
                Cells(i, 8).Copy
                Cells(j, 2).PasteSpecial
                Cells(i, 9).Copy
                Cells(j, 3).PasteSpecial

            j = j + 1
            End If
      i = i + 1
    Loop

'limpa dados utilizados
Range("E:Z").ClearContents
Range("A:Z").ClearFormats

'formata largura das colunas e valores como moeda
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
        Range("B2:C2").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.Font.Size = 12

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Cara, antes do ActiveWorkbook.Close, tenta ativar o Workbook que você quer fechar utilizando o comando Windows("C:\arquivoQueVoceQuerFechar").Activate. Testa aí e nos retorne se funcionou.

Comment: Já tinha tentado mas sem o windows na frente. Coloquei do jeito que disse e não funcionou também. Continua aparecendo o mesmo erro! :/ Será que pode ser porque ainda tem uma seleção ativa as planilhas?

Comment: Mesmo erro?! Estou intrigado, até apaguei a resposta rsrs. Vou fazer mais uns testes.

Comment: Cara, o seu código funciona perfeitamente aqui, com planilhas de teste que criei. Teria como disponibilizar as planilhas que você está testando?

Comment: Posso disponibilizar! Só não sei como faz! kkk.. da para fazer por aqui?

Comment: Também não sei se é possível por aqui, mas talvez você possa utilizar o google drive ou o one drive.

Comment: Pode ser! deixa eu te perguntar... Qual a sua versão do excel?

Comment: Estou usando o 2010.

Comment: As vezes é por causa da versão.. hj não vou ter mais tempo, mas semana que vem vou testar no 2010 para ver se funciona e te dou um retorno aqui! De qualquer forma, valeu pela ajuda

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78956/discussion-between-a-junior-and-leandro-lazari).

Answer (score 1):

Com esse trecho de código você poderá fechar qualquer pasta de trabalho.

```
Dim wb As Workbook

'nesse caso eu atribuiria uma referência a variável wb
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("<caminho\seuArquivo.xlsx>")

'com a referência atribuida ao WorkBook você pode fechar com o .Close
wb.Close
```